# Error removing user from ClientHandler

Tags: java, sockets

I have an error when a client closes the connection from the socket. What is supposed to happen is that the user closes their client, the server then receives this and should decrement the users who are connected which is stored in a relative integer value. However I receive an error relating to the for loop on the remove a user function.

```
public synchronized void removeUsers(Socket client,int clientUser)
        {
            int index=0;
            for (ClientHandler newHandler:userList)
            {
                if(newHandler.getUserId() == clientUser)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.close();
                        Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
                        userList.remove(index);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
```

Client handler run:

```
public void run()
        {
            String message;
            message = input.nextLine(); //Note method!
            getMessage(message);
            System.out.println(message.substring(0, count+1)+"-"+message.substring(count+1));
            while (!message.substring(0, count+1).equals("***CLOSE***"))
            {
                if(message.equals(user.getItemName(1)+"$status$")||  //checks for status of Ball
                        message.equals(user.getItemName(2)+"$status$"))
                {
                    if (user.BidItem(user.getItemName(1)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Top bid for " +             //posts for server
                            message.substring(0, count+1) + " is: "
                            + user.getTopBid(message.substring(0, count+1)));

                        output.println("Top bid for " +         //posts for client
                            message.substring(0, count+1) + " is: "
                            + user.getTopBid(message.substring(0, count+1))
                            + " by User" +
                            user.getTopBidder(message.substring(0, count+1)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("-1");
                        output.println("-1");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(user.BidItem(message.substring(count+2)))  //same but now for Plate
                    {
                        if(user.isGrtrThanTopBid(message.substring(count+2),
                                Double.parseDouble(message.substring(0, count+1))))
                        {
                            user.setTopBid(message.substring(count+2),
                                    Double.parseDouble(message.substring(0, count+1)), clientUser);
                            System.out.println("Bid Accepted for " + message.substring(count+2));
                            output.println("Bid Accepted for " + message.substring(count+2));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Low bid for " + message.substring(count+2));
                            output.println("Low bid for " + message.substring(count+2));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Late bid for " + message.substring(count+2));
                        output.println("Late bid for " + message.substring(count+2));
                    }
                }
                message = input.nextLine();
                count = 0;
                getMessage(message);
            }
            output.println(" messages received.");
            System.out.println("\n* Closing connection... *");
            user.removeUsers(client,clientUser);
        }
```

The full error is here:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Users.removeUsers(AuctionServer.java:211) //Relates to top of for loop
    at ClientHandler.run(AuctionServer.java:435)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove objects from lists when you iterates on them.

Try this.

Instead use a queue.

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList<Client>();
int index=0;
for (ClientHandler newHandler:userList)
{
    if(newHandler.getUserId() == clientUser)
    {
        try
        {
            client.close();
            Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
            queue.add(userList.get(index));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    index++;
}

while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
     userList.remove(queue.remove());
}
```